# Decimal and binary number handling

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a code which capable of converting decimal to a binary value. Comparing to other languages haskell needs few lines of code to bring this up. Below is the code i worked out.

```
binaryToDec :: [Int] -> Int
binaryToDec [] = []
binaryToDec (x:xs) = (+) (x * 2 ^(length xs))
```

this code gives an error which i tried so hard to figure out. but i couldn't.

```
Assignment.hs:61:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the expression: []
    In an equation for `binaryToDec': binaryToDec [] = []
```

what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean decimal-to-binary?   It's just a conversion to binary from some arbitrary number representation.  Haskell does not mandate decimal representation.  And few languages have since PL/I (FIXED DECIMAL(6)).

Answer (score 11):

```
binaryToDec :: [Int] -> Int
```

That says that `binaryToDec` is a function, which takes a list of `Int`s as its parameter, and returns an `Int` as its result.

```
binaryToDec [] = []
```

That says that when `binaryToDec`'s parameter is an empty list, its result is an empty list.

An empty list is not an `Int`, so this is an error.

Solution: decide what `binaryToDec []` should evaluate to, and use that on the right hand side of the equation.

But that's not all...

```
binaryToDec (x:xs) = (+) (x * 2 ^(length xs))
```

That says that when `binaryToDec`'s parameter is *not* an empty list, its result is a function that adds `x * 2 ^(length xs)` to *its* parameter.

A function is not an `Int`, so this is also an error.

Solution: work out what you want to add to `x * 2 ^(length xs)`, and, er, add it.

---

You have been stumped by error messages like this before. So let's deconstruct the error message line-by-line:

- `Assignment.hs:61:18:`

  This gives the filename, line number and approximate position on the line where the compiler decided there was an error.
- `` Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a0]' ``

  This means that the surrounding context expected a value of type `Int`, but the value provided was of type `[a0]`. (`a0` here means "don't know", so the compiler's worked out that you provided a list, but hasn't worked out what it's a list of.)
- `In the expression: []`

  This is the expression that has type `[a0]`, but was expected to have type `Int`. This is not always where your mistake is --- just where the compiler was when it noticed something was wrong --- but in this case it *is* where your mistake is: `[]` is clearly not an `Int`.

  (n.b. If the error was the `[]` on the left of the equals sign, the error message would have referred to the *pattern* `[]` instead of the *expression* `[]`.)
- `` In an equation for `binaryToDec': binaryToDec [] = [] ``

  This is just giving you a bit more context about where the compiler found the error.