# Higher order functions in haskell Error2

Tags: haskell

can you please tell me how to fix this error in my code?

```
{--------------------- BINARY TO DECIMAL MENU ---------------}

functionBinToDecimal:: IO()
functionBinToDecimal= do 
    putStrLn("\n\tConvert Binary To Decimal\n")
    putStrLn("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
    putStrLn("\t\tEnter a binary number : ") 
    input<-getLine
    let n=(read (reverse input))::String
    let result = convertionFrom binaryToDec n
    putStrLn(show result)

{----------------BINARY TO DECIMAL---------------------}

binaryToDec :: String -> Int
binaryToDec = foldr (\x s -> s * 2 + x) 0 . reverse . map charToInt 
    where charToInt x = if x == '0' then 0 else 1

conversionFrom :: (String -> Int) -> String -> Int
conversionFrom _ [] = 0
conversionFrom f (x:xs) = f x ++ conversionFrom f xs
```

Error

```
test.hs:28:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the expression: f x ++ conversionFrom f xs
    In an equation for `conversionFrom':
        conversionFrom f (x : xs) = f x ++ conversionFrom f xs
```

Comment: Sidenote: it is spelled "conversion", not "convertion."

Comment: Do you **understand** what the error message means? [I explained yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9177409/86622) how to read this sort of error message.

Answer (score 2):

Additional hint: You don't need to reverse, just use `foldl` instead of `foldr`, e.g.

```
binaryToDec = foldl (\n c -> 2*n + if c=='1' then 1 else 0) 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
convertionFrom :: (String -> Int) -> String -> Int
```

Says that your first argument is a function taking a string...

```
convertionFrom f (x:xs) = f x ++ convertionFrom f xs
```

is pattern matching, taking the second argument (a string), and binding `x` to the head of the string (a char).

So `f` expects a string, but you're passing it a char.

Answer (score 1):

Well you do  not need the conversionFrom function at all. The work of calculating the decimal form binary is binaryToDec, and using it alone works.

Comment: oki but i need a HOF (higher order function)

Comment: What do you think the first argument to foldr is? It is an anonymous function and you give it as parameter to a function. so there you have your HOF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the result of `f x` to the recursive call. You are now trying to prepend the result instead.

Try:

```
convenrtionFrom f (x : xs) = f x + convertionFrom f xs
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `++` is list concatenation, not addition - it expects and returns lists, but you are passing it ints and expect ints back.  That said, what is the point of `convertionFrom`?  `binaryToDec n` ought to convert a binary number in string form to an int without a problem.  Passing `binaryToDec` to `convertionFrom` can't be right, since calling `convertionFrom` on `binaryToDec` and a string will pass chars to `binaryToDec`, which will result in another type error, as noted by Mikel.

Answer (score 0):

Additional additional hint: There's already a function for converting a `String` to an `Int` (actually, any `Num` instance) with arbitrary base, it's called `Numeric.readInt`.  It's a HOF that requires two function arguments, so it's one better than `foldl`!

You can use `Char.digitToInt` to convert a digit `Char` to `Int` (instead of `charToInt`).